# React native Unable to use local tmp file path for Image.source iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Unable to use local temp file path for Image.source iOS.

```
    <Image 
      style={styles.containerRightCakeImageTag}
      source={{ 
        isStatic: true,
        uri: "file:///Users/md_007/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B450EF4D-7A43-4F2E-AE39-7D92427EBC7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/C2204990-8808-43C0-9678-F6A9CBA74998/Documents/6b66bfab94acc2d89d4c533a1d7ba767.jpeg" 
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: How to use  image get or Upload ?

Comment: its image is uploaded in local app data and its URI work in android perfect but issue in iOS only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use react-native-fs to get directories (which works for ios and android)

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
```

Image element looks like:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/directory/my.png'}} />
```

Answer (score 5):

When you read local files or images (for example images cached with [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image)) you have to add the "file://" only for Android platform and not for the iOS platform.

Here is some code in one of my apps:

```
let path = Platform.OS === "android" ? ('file://' + imageLocalUrl) : imageLocalUrl;
```

However, you'd better to use "react-native-fs" to read the file path and not use the simulator path as is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The image file must exist in the same folder as the .js file requiring it.

```
<Image source={require('./Logo.png')} />
```

or

The image file in your project folder and requiring it.

```
import Logo from '..' // set image path 

<Image source={require(Logo)} />
```

Comment: "file:///Users/md_007/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B450EF4D-7A43-4F2E-AE39-7D92427EBC7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/C2204990-8808-43C0-9678-F6A9CBA74998/Documents/6b66bfab94acc2d89d4c533a1d7ba767.jpeg"

its a full path of image its store into the app local data. its perfect work in Android and view the image but issue in iOS only.

Comment: @Asif vora Can you explain how you handled image in ios?
I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @KosalramRamaKrishnan 
look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/50757738/7833077 hope this is helpfull

Answer (score -2):

Use isStatic and uri in source match your need

```
const localUri = "file:///Users/md_007/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B450EF4D-7A43-4F2E-AE39-7D92427EBC7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/C2204990-8808-43C0-9678-F6A9CBA74998/Documents/6b66bfab94acc2d89d4c533a1d7ba767.jpeg" ;
<Image source={{ isStatic: true, uri: localUri }} />
```