# React Native, how to add a variable inside image link with require function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I stored images locally in project folder, and I want to add a variable (nature.png) inside image source (with require), so I did like this

```
let i = 'natrue';
let imagePath = require('../asset/gallery/image/');
    return (
        <View >
            <Image source={{imagePath} + i + '.png'}/>
        </View>
```

But I got an error:

```
text string must be rendered within a text component
```

And I dont want to do like this (Works fine) because I have more than 100 images:

```
<Image source={require('../asset/gallery/image/nature.png')} />
```

Comment: Maybe try and use `imagePath + i + '.png` instead (without the `{}` around imagePath)

Comment: @NickParsons I got same error

Comment: ReactNative's `<Image />` component's `source` prop has a type of `ImageSourcePropType`, not a String like you're trying pass it.  You could try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50757738/5648954) idea by passing an object with a `uri` or, you could stick with require and change the string: `require('../asset/gallery/image/' + i +'.png')`

Comment: @NickParsons I got an error Unable to resolve module

Answer (score 1):

Unfournately `requirejs` module doesn't work that way

You'll have to create strings completely or create a object which will map a `key` to image. Also that is a best practice to follow.

you can create a file called image.js and export all your images from there,

for example

```js
// image.js

const BASE_URL = "../asset/gallery/image/";

export default {
  nature:require(`${BASE_URL}nature.png`),
}
```

and in your components,

```js
import Images from "src/images";

...
<>
   <Image src={Images.nature}/>
</>
...
```