# How to get real Directory Path on iOS in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fs

I want to download a file in React Native and save it in a Directory selected by the User (e.g. Downloads).

Right now I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker to let the user pick a directory and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0 to download the file.

Unfortunately, react-native-document-picker only gives me a dynamic URI to the directory, which does not exist when react-native-fs tries to access it. I think it's hidden behind something like a File-Provider.

I searched a lot but found no solution on how to get the real static path to a directory. Might be that I am missing something obvious, but I can not figure it out right now.

the code (simplified)

```
DocumentPicker.pickDirectory().then(pick => {

  // this looks something like:
  // file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/8443...EC/File%20Provider%20Storage/Downloads/
  const pickedDirectory = pick.uri;

  // resolves to false:
  RNFS.exists(pickedDirectory)

  // does not work
  RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: downloadUrl,
    toFile: pickedDirectory + filename,
  }).promise.then(r => { console.log(r)
});
```

Comment: What else you're getting in `pickedDirectory ` ?  There is something more I believe.

Comment: pickedDirectory ist just an object with an uri {uri: string} nothing more

Comment: object looks like this on simulator but i tested on device also ```{"uri": "file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4397173C-E2B4-4E1A-9FAE-980CAD057627/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA2871AF-D874-4960-AECE-8BE0B9B0861D/File%20Provider%20Storage/Downloads/"}```

Answer (score -1):

Either we can opt for the solution give on the below link (using `react-native-fs`).

[React native Unable to use local tmp file path for Image.source iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755784/react-native-unable-to-use-local-tmp-file-path-for-image-source-ios)

or try

Add `copyTo:"documentDirectory"`  in the pick document options. Then in `pickedDirectory.fileCopyUri`  you'll get the document path.

What happens is when we pick any Item from gallery or iOS file system, it picks and place it a temporary directory for some time, then it get auto removed from that directory. Try the above given solution, I believe It will work.

Comment: pickDirectory does not accept this option unfortunately. the only options it accepts is about how the picker-view is presented

Comment: have you tried `pick()` ? I think that can also fulfil your purpuse. I'll try in my local and will share more specific answer.

Comment: i tried pick. the problem is, that i want to pick a directory (into which the file gets downloaded) not a file. i tried pik({type: "public.folder"}) but that does not compile. thank you for your help!

Comment: Then try `react-native-fs` you'll get it sorted for sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755784/react-native-unable-to-use-local-tmp-file-path-for-image-source-ios

Here is the solution for you @DeepValue